# Can't pass lambda that calls member function as C++11 thread ctor argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

I would like to pass a lambda that calls a member function as an argument to the thread constructor but have been unable to. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <thread>

class Foo {
    void run(void func()) {
        func();
    }

    void bar() {
        return;
    }

    void bof() {
        std::thread thread(&Foo::run, this, [&]{bar();}); // This fails to compile
    }
};
```

The above results in the following error:

```
$ g++ --std=c++11 -c funcThreadArg.cpp 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:39:0,
                 from funcThreadArg.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(void (*)())>(Foo*, Foo::bof()::__lambda0)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Foo::*)(void (*)()); _Args = {Foo* const, Foo::bof()::__lambda0}]’
funcThreadArg.cpp:14:62:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(void (*)())>(Foo*, Foo::bof()::__lambda0)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Foo::*)(void (*)())>(Foo*, Foo::bof()::__lambda0)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

Is what I want to do possible? If so, how?

Comment: You cannot convert a lambda that captures into a function pointer.

Comment: On gcc 11.2 the error says "error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues"

Comment: Change it to `[](Foo* _this){ _this->bar(); }` and `void run(void (*func)(Foo*))`.. then call `func(this)`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `std::function` in `Foo::run()`

```cpp
class Foo {
    void run(std::function<void()> func) {
        func();
    }

    void bar() {
        return;
    }

    void bof() {
        std::thread thread(&Foo::run, this, [this](){ bar(); });
        thread.join();
    }
};
```

Comment: Here is a working example: https://godbolt.org/z/aYcY6ETW3